# how to correct the spacing of texts?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I made this  blog but when I write a post in the write a new post page the spaces between the lines and all that is correct but when I post it and go to detail.html to see it it all just displays beneath each other with no space between the lines what should I do? if I need to post another page please let me know
I appreciate your help

new.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}



<form method="post">
  <style>
    textarea {
  resize: none;
}
  </style>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div style="margin-top: 15px"></div>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Post</legend>
          {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
       
        <div class="form-group">
          <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
      </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<html>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
  <body class="text-center" style="line-height: 2;">
    <article>
      <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
      <p style="margin-top: 15px;">{{post.body}}</p>
    </article>
  </body>
  <div style="margin-top: 24px"></div>
  <a style="color: darkgray; font-size: 22px;"> <img  src="{% static 'website/icons8-sparkles-25.png'%}"> Written by {{post.author}} <img  src="{% static 'website/icons8-sparkles-25.png'%}"> </a>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

[looks like this while writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMpXu.png)
[looks like this when posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlqhH.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django Built-in tags [Linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) in your *post.body*.

The code look like this:

```
{{post.body|linebreaks}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "pre" tag in html. It preserves both spaces and line breaks. I guess it would help in this case.

```
<pre>{{post.body}}</pre>
```